# Error when parsing system time through SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, string-formatting, systemtime

I'd like to get the current system time, and then parse it through a formatter `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`.

I get `.... error : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 13 17:05:51 PST 2015"` using in the approach below:

```
public static void currentSystemTime() {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {
        System.out.println(format.parse(calendar.getTime().toString()));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DateDifference.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

How can I get the system time in a literal format that matches `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`?

Comment: Why? Why not just use LocalDateTime.Now() to get the current time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to format the current time (a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)) to [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) but [`DateFormat.parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) does the opposite.

Use [`DateFormat.format(Date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) for what you want to achieve:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

**Note:**

The constructor [`new Date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date--) allocates a `Date` object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond. So no need to use `Calendar` to get the current time.

**Alternative:**

There are multiple overloads of the `format()` method in `SimpleDateFormat`, one which takes a general `Object` argument:

[`Format.format(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format-java.lang.Object-)

This also accepts the formattable date/time as a `Long` being the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. So the following also works without creating a `Date` instance:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is error, use:

```
System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
```